# Riemann's zeta as a continued fraction over prime numbers.

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, continued-fractions

Riemann's zeta function is a function with many faces, I mean representations. I recently derived this one, bellow, as a continued fraction over prime numbers.

$$
\zeta(s)=1
+\cfrac{\frac{1}{2^{s}}}{1-\frac{1}{2^{s}}
-\cfrac{\frac{2^{s}-1}{3^{s}}}{1+\frac{2^{s}-1}{3^{s}}
-\cfrac{\frac{3^{s}-1}{5^{s}}}{1+\frac{3^{s}-1}{5^{s}}
-\cfrac{\frac{5^{s}-1}{7^{s}}}{1+\frac{5^{s}-1}{7^{s}}
-\cfrac{\frac{7^{s}-1}{11^{s}}}{1+\frac{7^{s}-1}{11^{s}}
-\ddots}}}}}
$$

... and I'd like to know if this is known in the literature and if so I'd appreciate to have references about it.

Thanks.

Comment: "Found" in the sense of derived it yourself, or found it in a written source somewhere? If the latter, you might include that source here.

Comment: @Jack M, I derived it myself.

Comment: Please show your derivation. Thank you.

Comment: @marty, ok, I'll do that.

Comment: Some references: http://mathoverflow.net/q/163113/16888

Comment: @FredKline, Thanks, but I already knew [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84108/the-riemanns-zeta-function-represented-as-a-continued-fraction-and-a-question-o) one... and none of the others is "over primes".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The continued fraction representation above had its origins on another problem I was working on sometime ago.

It's based on a very simple way of looking at the *Euler's product* representation of $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$. Interestingly it applies to every infinite product.

And this is as follows

$$
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right)\frac{1}{3^s}-\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^s}\right)\frac{1}{5^s}-\cdots
$$

From here its easy to derive the above continued fraction using [Euler's continued fraction formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula).

And thats it, It's nice and eventually a new thing.

**EDIT**

Just to make it clear, note that
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}&=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right)\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{3^s}\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{3^s}\right)\frac{1}{5^s}-\left(1-\frac{1}{3^s}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5^s}\right)\frac{1}{7^s}-\cdots\right]\\
&=\left(1-\frac{1}{2^s}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3^s}\right)\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{5^s}\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{5^s}\right)\frac{1}{7^s}-\cdots\right]\\
&\vdots\\
&=\prod_{p\in\mathbb{P}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^{s}}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of the prime numbers.

**EDIT**

To derive the continued faction just put $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ in the form
$$
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=1-\frac{1}{2^s}\left(1+\frac{2^s-1}{3^s}\left(1+\frac{3^s-1}{5^s}\left(1+\frac{5^s-1}{7^s}\left(1+\frac{7^s-1}{11^s}\left(1+\ddots\right ) \right ) \right ) \right ) \right)
$$
and then just apply the [Euler continued fraction formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula).
So we can write this as
$$
\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=1-\frac{1}{2^s}-\frac{1}{2^s}\frac{2^s-1}{3^s}-\frac{1}{2^s}\frac{2^s-1}{3^s}\frac{3^s-1}{5^s}-\frac{1}{2^s}\frac{2^s-1}{3^s}\frac{3^s-1}{5^s}\frac{5^s-1}{7^s}-\cdots 
$$
Now, let $a_1=-\frac{1}{2^s};a_2=\frac{2^s-1}{3^s};a_3=\frac{3^s-1}{5^s};a_4=\frac{5^s-1}{7^s}\cdots$ and we'll get the Euler continued fraction formula.

Comment: Found this: http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4015

Comment: Can you expand on the last step.? I didn't get it.

Comment: @user230452, I added some clarification.

Answer (score 3):

By using *Mathematica* to simplify the first 7 primes, we get:
$$\frac{510510^s}{\left(2^s-1\right) \left(3^s-1\right) \left(5^s-1\right) \left(7^s-1\right) \left(11^s-1\right) \left(13^s-1\right) \left(17^s-1\right)},$$ which is equivalent to:
$$\prod _{p\text{ prime}} \frac{p^s}{p^s-1} = \zeta(s).$$
Product does not converge when $s=1.$

Scroll down to [Euler product formula (2nd paragraph)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).
When $s=1\text{, }\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p^s}}$ simplifies to $\frac{p}{p-1}.$   When $s>1,$ there is no simplification.

Neves's formula puts the exponents back onto the primes when it is simplified, $\frac{p^s}{p^s-1}.$

Comment: Thats $\zeta(s)$ in the Euler's product form...

Comment: @Neves, we crossed paths. My last edit explains.