# Riemann Zeta circularity?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

[In this post I show:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/748949/28555)
$$\prod _{p\text{ prime}} \frac{p^s}{p^s-1} = \zeta(s).$$
*Wolfram Alpha* shows an alternate form for the primes:
$$\frac{p_n{}^2}{p_n{}^2-1}=\frac{\left(\sum _{k=1}^{2^n} \left\lfloor \left(\frac{n}{\pi (k)+1}\right)^{1/n}\right\rfloor +1\right){}^2}{\left(\sum _{k=1}^{2^n} \left\lfloor \left(\frac{n}{\pi (k)+1}\right)^{1/n}\right\rfloor +1\right){}^2-1},
$$
and I note the prime counting function. I read somewhere that $\zeta(1)$ is equivalent to the Prime Number Theorem, so I have this question.

Would using primes to prove RH be circular? Or, is the fact that $s=1$ is a pole in the complex plane, mean there is no circularity?

Comment: Both identities can be proved directly, without reference to the prime number theorem or the Riemann hypothesis or each other. So there's no circularity.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in this: [Are Primes a Self-Fulfilling Prophecy?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97981/are-primes-a-self-fulfilling-prophecy) Sorry for the self-promotion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both identities can be proved directly, without reference to the prime number theorem or the Riemann hypothesis or each other. So there's no circularity.